# Null pointer exception for my method in a LinkedList implementation

Tags: java, data-structures

I am constructing a FrequencyBag that will take something like an Integer, String or Character, and it will take the data and pair it with its frequency.

For example:

```
 FrequencyBag<Integer> fb = new FrequencyBag<Integer>();

  fb.add(cat);
  fb.add(dog);
  fb.add(horse);
  fb.add(cat);
  fb.add(cat);
```

will look like

```
 (cat,3) ---> (dog,1) ---> (horse, 1)
```

My method getMaxFreq() has no problem getting the max frequency (which is 3 for the example above)  when the bag contains elements, but when I try to return the value 0 for an empty null FrequencyBag() I get this error.

"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException"
"FrequencyBag$Node.access$1(FrequencyBag.java:8)"

Here is my method below:

```
    public int getMaxFreq() {

    Node<T> currentNode = firstNode;
    Node<T> nextNode = firstNode.next;

    int compareVal = nextNode.freq;
    int maxVal = currentNode.freq;

    if (currentNode == null) {
        maxVal = 0;
        return maxVal;
    }

    while (nextNode.next != null) {

        if (maxVal < compareVal) {
            maxVal = compareVal;
        }

        else {
            // Do nothing
        }

        currentNode = currentNode.next;
        nextNode = nextNode.next;
    }

    if (nextNode.next == null) {
        if (maxVal < nextNode.freq) {
            maxVal = nextNode.freq;
        } else {
            // Do nothing
        }

        return maxVal;
    }

    return maxVal;

}
```

---

Instead of getting a null pointer error, I want to do this when I create an empty bag and call my getMaxFreq() method:

```
 FrequencyBag<Integer> emptyBag = new FrequencyBag<Integer>();

 System.out.println("Output: " + emptyBag.getMaxFreq());

 Output: 0
```

Comment: What's holding you back?

Comment: I am not exactly sure why I am getting a null pointer exception.

Comment: My if(currentNode == null) statement should have handled that, but I still get an error.

Comment: If you are not sure where a null pointer exception occurs, you can make possible null values explicit by using an option type, such as the `Optional` type defined by Guava: http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Optional.html. It's generally good to not wildly pass around null values. But to simply discover where your null pointer exception happens, you can also just step through your code with the debugger.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try first checking if currentNode == null before trying to dereference 'currentNode' on line 7 (it seems), this line -> int maxVal = currentNode.freq;

Otherwise you are trying to dereference a null pointer which is was is liking throwing that nullPointerException

The same applies to 'nextNode'